# How to compile and use QuaZip on Windows? Do I need to separately install zlib?

Tags: c++, qt, mingw, zlib, quazip

I need to create a simple .zip file with bitmaps inside. I'm using Qt, so I'd like the library I'm using for that to be similar to Qt as much as possible. After googling for a while I was sure that QuaZip is a perfect solution. But I fail to install it, maybe because my machine is Windows. On QuaZip SourceForge page there are only sources to download. After downloading I tried running qmake and mingw32-make from the Qt command prompt in the quazip-0.3 dir. Here's the output:

```
Z:\quazip-0.3>mingw32-make
cd quazip\ && mingw32-make -f Makefile
mingw32-make[1]: Entering directory `Z:/quazip-0.3/quazip'
mingw32-make -f Makefile.Debug
mingw32-make[2]: Entering directory `Z:/quazip-0.3/quazip'
gcc -c -g -Wall -DUNICODE -DQT_LARGEFILE_SUPPORT -DQT_DLL -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_THR
EAD_SUPPORT -I"c:\Qt\2010.05\qt\include\QtCore" -I"c:\Qt\2010.05\qt\include" -I"
." -I"c:\Qt\2010.05\qt\include\ActiveQt" -I"debug" -I"c:\Qt\2010.05\qt\mkspecs\w
in32-g++" -o debug\ioapi.o ioapi.c
ioapi.c:13:18: error: zlib.h: No such file or directory
In file included from ioapi.c:14:
ioapi.h:38: error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before '*' token
ioapi.h:38: error: function definition declared 'typedef'
ioapi.h:38: warning: return type defaults to 'int'
ioapi.h: In function 'voidpf':
ioapi.h:38: error: expected declaration specifiers before 'OF'
ioapi.h:39: error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before '*' token
ioapi.h:39: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'OF'
ioapi.h:40: error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before '*' token
ioapi.h:40: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'OF'
ioapi.h:41: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'OF'
ioapi.h:42: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'OF'
ioapi.h:43: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'OF'
```

Now, the line **"ioapi.c:13:18: error: zlib.h: No such file or directory"** kind of means zlib is missing. But shouldn't zlib be included with Qt? Qt dependends on zlib, doesn't it?