# How to build Quazip 0.5.1 on Windows 7?

Tags: qt, quazip

I'm trying to build the quazip libary (version 0.5.1) on Windows 7 (32-bit) with Qt 5.0.1 32-Bit LGPL installed.

When i run in the Qt-Commandprompt:

```
qmake
mingw32-make
```

with the directory set to the folder in which I extracted Quazip (C:\Qt\quazip-0.5.1\quazip), I get the following error-log:

```
C:\Qt\quazip-0.5.1\quazip>mingw32-make
mingw32-make -f Makefile.Release
mingw32-make[1]: Entering directory 'C:/Qt/quazip-0.5.1/quazip'
g++ -Wl,-s -shared -mthreads -Wl,--out-implib,release\libquazip.a -o release\qua
zip.dll object_script.quazip.Release  -LC:\Qt\Qt5\5.0.1\mingw47_32\lib -lQt5Core
./release\unzip.o:unzip.c:(.text+0x1008): undefined reference to `crc32'
./release\unzip.o:unzip.c:(.text+0x10aa): undefined reference to `inflate'
./release\unzip.o:unzip.c:(.text+0x10da): undefined reference to `crc32'
./release\unzip.o:unzip.c:(.text+0x1110): undefined reference to `crc32'
./release\unzip.o:unzip.c:(.text+0x1327): undefined reference to `inflateEnd'
./release\unzip.o:unzip.c:(.text+0x1727): undefined reference to `get_crc_table'
./release\unzip.o:unzip.c:(.text+0x186f): undefined reference to `inflateInit2_'
./release\zip.o:zip.c:(.text+0xac7): undefined reference to `crc32'
./release\zip.o:zip.c:(.text+0xb7c): undefined reference to `deflate'
./release\zip.o:zip.c:(.text+0xcdf): undefined reference to `deflate'
./release\zip.o:zip.c:(.text+0xef5): undefined reference to `deflateEnd'
./release\zip.o:zip.c:(.text+0x13a8): undefined reference to `get_crc_table'
./release\zip.o:zip.c:(.text+0x1af9): undefined reference to `deflateInit2_'
./release\quaadler32.o:quaadler32.cpp:(.text+0x2e): undefined reference to `adle
r32'
./release\quaadler32.o:quaadler32.cpp:(.text+0x61): undefined reference to `adle
r32'
./release\quaadler32.o:quaadler32.cpp:(.text+0xa1): undefined reference to `adle
r32'
./release\quaadler32.o:quaadler32.cpp:(.text+0xb1): undefined reference to `adle
r32'
c:/qt/qt5/tools/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.7.2/../../../../i686-w64
-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: ./release\quaadler32.o: bad reloc address 0x0 in section `.
rdata$_ZTI13QuaChecksum32[__ZTI13QuaChecksum32]'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile.Release:106: recipe for target 'release\quazip.dll' failed
mingw32-make[1]: *** [release\quazip.dll] Error 1
mingw32-make[1]: Leaving directory 'C:/Qt/quazip-0.5.1/quazip'
makefile:34: recipe for target 'release' failed
mingw32-make: *** [release] Error 2
```

But in my Zlib-Folder (C:\Qt\Qt5\5.0.1\Src\qtbase\src\3rdparty\zlib) are all this listed files installed.

.

As I tried to solve the problem, I have added into the quazip.pro and into the quazip.pri:

```
INCLUDEPATH += $$[QT_INSTALL_PREFIX]/src/3rdparty/zlib
```

, how it is suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4449467/how-to-compile-and-use-quazip-on-windows-do-i-need-to-separately-install-zlib).

All other solutiuons I have found on Google so far aren't helping.

I hope someone of you can help me.

Greetings,
LVreg

Comment: I had to explicitly use the `INCLUDEPATH` and `LIBS` when calling `qmake` from the command line, like: `qmake PREFIX=../install LIBS+=<path/to/zlib.a> INCLUDEPATH+=<path/to/zlib/includes>`. Putting this in the `pro` file didn't work for me either.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that QuaZIP can not find the zlib library. You should include the path of the headers an also the libraries when you run qmake:

```
qmake "INCLUDEPATH+=C:/Qt/Qt5/5.0.1/Src/qtbase/src/3rdparty/zlib" "LIBS+=-LC:/Qt/Qt5/5.0.1/Src/qtbase/src/3rdparty/zlib -lz"
mingw32-make
```

There is a full explanation in my blog if you want to check it out: http://www.antonioborondo.com/2014/10/22/zipping-and-unzipping-files-with-qt/

Comment: This worked for me, not when I ran it in `quazip-0.7.1` but when I ran it in `quazip-0.7.1/quazip`. Not sure, but I guess the parameters don't propagate when the .pro files invoke other .pro files.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what worked for me (QuaZip 0.7 on Windows 7 compiled with MSVC13 32 bits):

In the command line type:

```
SET INCLUDE=<PathToZib\include>;%INCLUDE%
SET LIB=<PathToZib\lib>;%LIB%
qmake PREFIX=<FolderWhereInstallWillPutFiles> LIBS+=<PathToZib\lib>/zdll.lib
nmake
nmake install
```

everything between <> must be changed to your applicable path

NOTE:
in the LIBS+= part use / instead of \ as folders delimiter

Answer (score 0):

try to make the lib of quazip on windows - look here:

https://www.maefloresta.com/wiki/doku.php?id=quazip_windows

but - try the following command - instead of "make" take "mingw32-make".