# Is it possible to modify QT qmake variable in the parent subdirs project?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qmake, qtconcurrent

I have the shared library project with structure like this:

library.pro:

```
TEMPLATE = subdirs
CONFIG  += ordered
SUBDIRS += libs plugins test_programs
...
QT += concurrent
...
# Those files contains pure interfaces (C++ abstract classes)
# with no implementation, and some helper classes with inline implementation.
# So there is no reason to create yet another subproject for them
HEADERS += iface/IInterface1.h \   
           iface/IInterface2.h \ # IInterface2 needs QtConcurrent
           ...
```

IInterface2.h:

```
...
#include <QtConcurrent> // ERROR HERE: file not found, i.e. qmake ignores
                        // "QT += concurrent" statement in library.pro

class MyHelperExc : public QtConcurrent::Exception
{ ... }

class IInterface2: public virtual IBaseInterface
{ ... }
```

So, my problem is: qmake just ignores variable operations in `SUBDIRS` parent project.
But it works ok in subprojects.
What am i doing wrong?

Comment: @dtech, have you ever worked around this issue?  I'd love the ability to do what eraxillan is suggesting.  I'm incorporating [QuaZip](https://github.com/stachenov/quazip) into my project, but I'm hitting build issues like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15648669/how-to-build-quazip-0-5-1-on-windows-7) that means I have to modify the quazip.pro files to link against zlibwapi.dll during build.  Thus, I have to maintain a separate quazip git repo, which is a real bummer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
TEMPLATE = subdirs
```

This line says that library.pro is just a container for other projects, contained within the subdirectories listed in the `SUBDIRS` variable. Most other variables in library.pro are ignored, except `CONFIG += ordered`, which specifies that the subdirectories should be processed in the order in which they are given.

The subprojects which include IInterface2.h all need to have `QT += concurrent` in their .pro files.

Answer (score 0):

> What am i doing wrong?

The fact that you think qmake would parse, however that is not how qmake is currently working. SUBDIRS will mean that it will only look in subfolders.

Comment: So, in library.pro `qmake` process only `SUBDIRS` variable and don't care about all others?

Comment: @Axilles: that is not fair, but sources and headers will be ignored at that stage.

Comment: But if headers/sources in library.pro will be ignored, at what stage compiler process them and produces an error? I'm just trying to understand where to place `QT += concurrent` statement ;(

Comment: @Axilles: the problem is not with that statement, but your HEADERS in library.pro. The best would be if you could upload a tarball with a sample project, reproducing the issue, and I could provide a concrete recommendation.

Comment: Ok, i made it: http://yadi.sk/d/BBhA24glKARVT
This is a minimalistic subdirs project where my problem reproduces.

Comment: Thanks, so I suggest to create iface.pro and and the iface to the subdirs. SUBDIRS are not meant to be fixed with SOURCES and HEADERS.

Comment: So i'm forced to create additional subproject for iface. Ok. Thank you for your time that was wasted...
However, in my opinion this solution does not follows Unix "KISS" principle ;( And my programmer soul is sad.

Comment: @Axilles: you do not necessarily need to create a new subproject (or .pri include project file). You can also just include it from elsewhere where that variable will take effect.

Comment: So i need empty subproject with QT += concurrent. Now it's clear to me :)

Comment: @Axilles: I meant that you could use use INCLUDEPATH=wherever/the/header/is from the .pro file some file(s) of which will include your interface header.

Comment: @Axilles: interesting that you withdrew the answer in favor of another, which basically writes the same as I wrote to you. :) Perhaps, I was not as clear as the other answer in my comments.

Comment: The other man write the main thought of your comments in the answer, in the clear way. Nothing personal :D

Comment: @Axilles: ok, I wished to update the answer though, but good that you got what you have wished. I gave a +1 on the question either way. Good luck.

Comment: Yep, i'm very need of some luck :D With such complicated things like Qt and C++ this is necessary... Hope you will continue help to Qt ungrateful funs like me ;)