# How to register custom type with QML if it is passed as const from C++

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I have a C++ class called `MyClass`. This class is registered as an uncreatable type so it can be referred by name in QML.

`MyClass.h`:

```
#pragma once

#include <QObject>

class MyClass : public QObject {
Q_OBJECT

public:
    static void initQML();

    MyClass();
    MyClass(const MyClass &myClass);
    ~MyClass();

    Q_INVOKABLE void printText();
};
```

`MyClass.cpp`:

```
#include "MyClass.h"

#include <QtQml>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QMetaType>

/*static*/ void MyClass::initQML() {
    qmlRegisterUncreatableType<const MyClass>("Test", 1, 0, "MyClass", "Don't create it");

    qRegisterMetaType<const MyClass*>("const MyClass*");
}

MyClass::MyClass() {
    qDebug() << "Constructor called.";
}

MyClass::MyClass(const MyClass &myClass) {
    qDebug() << "Copy constructor called.";
}

MyClass::~MyClass() {
    qDebug() << "Destructor called.";
}

void MyClass::printText() {
    qDebug() << "This a sample text.";
}
```

I have another class which is called `MyClassFactory`. This class creates `MyClass` objects. It is registered as a singleton type to QML.

`MyClassFactory.h`:

```
#pragma once

#include "MyClass.h"

#include <QObject>

class MyClassFactory : public QObject {
Q_OBJECT

public:
    static void initQML();

    MyClassFactory();

public slots:
    static const MyClass *makeDefaultMyClass();
};
```

`MyClassFactory.cpp`:

```
#include "MyClassFactory.h"

#include <QtQml>
#include <QQmlEngine>
#include <QJSEngine>

QObject *simpleQmlRegisterSingletonTypeCallback(QQmlEngine *, QJSEngine *) {
    return new MyClassFactory();
}

/*static*/ void MyClassFactory::initQML() {
    qmlRegisterSingletonType<MyClassFactory>("Test", 1, 0, "MyClassFactory",
                                             simpleQmlRegisterSingletonTypeCallback);
}

MyClassFactory::MyClassFactory() {}

/*static*/ const MyClass* MyClassFactory::makeDefaultMyClass() {
    return new MyClass();
}
```

In my `main.qml` I create a property of `MyClass` type and bind a value to it via `MyClassFactory`. Here is my `main.qml`:

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2

import Test 1.0

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true

    width: 480
    height: 272

    property MyClass myClass: MyClassFactory.makeDefaultMyClass()

    Button {
        anchors.centerIn: parent

        text: "Create MyClass"

        onClicked: myClass.printText()
    }
}
```

When I build and run my code, I get the following error in the console:

`qrc:/main.qml:12: Error: Unknown method return type: const MyClass*`

If I register `const MyClass*` as a meta type, then this error disappears, but I get another one:

`qrc:/main.qml:12:31: Unable to assign const MyClass* to MyClass*`

First of all why do I have to register `const MyClass*` as a meta type, if I have already registered `const MyClass` as a QML (uncreatable) type?

Main question is how do I pass a const pointer to QML?

For a full running example, here is my `main.cpp`:

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>

#include "MyClass.h"
#include "MyClassFactory.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);

    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    // Init

    MyClass::initQML();
    MyClassFactory::initQML();

    // Main loop

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));

    return app.exec();
}
```

I use Qt 5.9.5.

Comment: why not just pass  `MyClass` instead of `const MyClass`?

Comment: I could pass `MyClass` instead of `const MyClass` and that is what I am doing currently, but I would like to learn how to do it with `const` or if it is not possible to do it with `const`, then why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The errors you are getting are making it clear that it wouldn't work with `const` anyway you twist it, because that's not how the API is designed, because while you can pass non-const objects to const functions, you cannot do the opposite for reasons that should be obvious. And it doesn't make a lot of sense that this particular API will have a const-correct side, at least in the version of Qt you are using.

Up until recently, JS didn't really have a notion of constants. It was introduced in ECMA 2015, but that specification is currently still not supported in QML anyway. Qt 5.12 will implement it, but even then, I doubt it will be integrated with the C++ side of things from the start. Properly propagating const correctness would be a nice thing to have, but then again, seeing how null pointer variants still pass `if` checks in QML, I wouldn't be holding my breath...

There exists the notion of read only properties, but that's really not the same as constants, it is just properties that cannot be assigned a different value, if the value happens to be an object, it can still be modified.

So the easiest thing to do if you want it to be a constant is to simply **not** expose an interface to make changes to that object.

Also, there shouldn't be any need to register `QObject` derived type pointers if you are using `qmlRegisterUncreatableType()`, `qmlRegisterType()`, `qmlRegisterSingletonType()` or similar for those types.

Comment: Thanks a lot @dtech for your explanation. I had the feeling that this is the case, but I wanted to have an additional input on it.

Comment: @dtech, can you look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22270456/is-it-possible-to-modify-qt-qmake-variable-in-the-parent-subdirs-project#comment92670865_22270456)  I'm wondering if you've ever solved it a different way.